# Inheritance private fields in java

Tags: java

private fields don't inheritance so in class B doesn't exist z but method setz(int a) exist!

```
class A{
   private int z=1;

   public void setz(int a){
      z=a;
   }
}

class B extends A{
}
```

if new an object of class B and call setz(int a) z changed but this method should have errors becuse z not exist !how can explanation it?

Comment: What makes you think that `z` doesn't exist? Just because you can't access it from `B`, doesn't mean it isn't there.

Comment: it still exists, B just can't see it.

Comment: Even if it exist but you say that is not accessible in Class B but this method (setz()) call in B class and must access to z to change it !!??

Answer (score 6):

Your thought that `z` shouldn't exist in a `B` is incorrect.  It's true that `private` variables are not inherited, but that doesn't stop it from existing.  It's just inaccessible from `B`.

Comment: is correct, B.z would fail but B.setz(a) would work fine, because setz is public

Answer (score 2):

`setz(int a)` would not have an error as it is public. Moreover, `z` still exists in the parent class.

```
B b = new B();
b.z = 1;  // Error because z is a private member of A
b.setz(1); // No error because setz() is a public method of A
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to change it, you can access to `z`, you can write method `public int getZ()` in class A, and you can call it for instance of class `B`.

```
public int getZ() { 
    return z;
}
```

And you will can access as following:

```
B b = new B();
b.getZ();
```